What needs to be passed for IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>?
How can I pass a method a IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
A method I'm working with expects this as a parameter, but I can't for the life of me figure out what that should be. I've tried Dictionary<string, List<string>> and Visual Studio wants to cast it as the above, but then throws an error when it does.

What is your source of data?

While Dictionary<..> does implement IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>, List<string> != IEnumerable<string> that's a variance problem.

Visual Studio isn't asking you to cast it. It's tell you that it can't.

Without using dictionary:
We can simplify your issue as ->
IEnumerable<Dictionary<'key', 'value'>>  where your 'key' is of string type and 'value' is of type IEnumerable<string> type.
Pls note that: IEnumerable is an interface you are using whereas, List is a class which implements IEnumerable and few other interfaces internally. So, according to your question its better to pass IEnumerable<string> instead of List<string>. As IEnumerable is an interface and is not made to add any element, so we can initialse it as a List.
Reference code:
You can pass something like this to your parameter:
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> value = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();

//Adding the values seperately to demonstrate how to use it.
var newValue1 = new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>("key1", new List<string> { "value1", "value2" });
var newValue2 = new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>("key2", new List<string> { "value3", "value4" });

//Concatenating newValue1 and newValue2 to updatedValue.
var updatedValue = value.Concat(new List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> { newValue1, newValue2 });

//Iterating to show the values in updatedValue
foreach(var pair in updatedValue){
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {pair.Key}");

    // Iterate over the values of each KeyValuePair
    foreach(var val in pair.Value){
         Console.WriteLine($"Value: {val}");
         }
    }

Output:
Key: key1
Value: value1
Value: value2
Key: key2
Value: value3
Value: value4

Now, if your method looks something like:
public static MyMethod(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> value)
{
   //Some wonderful code.
}

You will now be able to pass value as a parameter.
I hope this explanation works.

Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for.

You have a method with this signature:
void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> input)

You have source data in the form of Dictionary<string, List<string>> data.
You call it this way:
SomeMethod(data.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(x.Key, x.Value)));

Just because Dictionary<TKey, TValue> implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> & List<string> implements IEnumerable<string>, it does not mean that Dictionary<string, List<string>> is castable to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>. It's not.
Had your method had the signature void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> input) then you would have been fine.
